want to decrease number of rows by putting size of same item into column to decrease sheet size
I have excel sheet of more than 1000 item name in which single item contain different sizes (which making sheet long) I want to separate sizes from name and want to put them on top row so that same name have there size in a single line with there rate. as shown in image want to convert table 1 to table 2

I tried this formula
=MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",CHAR(1),LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))))+1,LEN(A2))
but only separate size but I am not able to put those size in a single row please tell me how to put these size in a single row for same name with there rates


If you keep that column you created with the sizes you could then use the TRANSPOSE function to make it into a row? Is that what you're trying to achieve?

please watch image 1 ,I want to do that

Unless you are using a newer version of Excel than 2007/2010 the best solution is to simply use a Pivot Table.

It is doable with a bunch of fairly convoluted array formulas but can be easily done with a single formula in Excel2019/O365.  If you are using an older version of Excel just create a Pivot Table - that's exactly what they were made for.

how to separate shirt rn from 80 in case of thousands of name list, typing manually shirt and pant is easy but I have list of item more than 2.5k in such manner

how it is possible with  single formula in Excel2019/O365, I will install new version tell me how to do

You can use Flash Fill to separate the names without using any formulas.

Here are two ways using Excel Formulas which is exclusively applicable to MS365 and using Power Query which works with Excel 2010+ onwards:
• Using Excel Formulas


• Formula used in cell D1
=LET(
     _Data, A2:B7,
     _Name, TEXTBEFORE(TAKE(_Data,,1)," "),
     _Size, TEXTAFTER(TAKE(_Data,,1)," ",-1),
     _UniqName, UNIQUE(_Name),
     _UniqSize, TOROW(UNIQUE(_Size)),
     VSTACK(HSTACK(A1, _UniqSize), HSTACK(_UniqName,
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_UniqName), COLUMNS(_UniqSize), LAMBDA(r,c,
     FILTER(TAKE(_Data,,-1), (_Name=INDEX(_UniqName,r))*(_Size=INDEX(_UniqSize,c)),""))))))


• This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)


To use Power Query follow the steps:

First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as Table1



Next, open a blank query from Data Tab --> Get & Transform Data --> Get Data --> From Other Sources --> Blank Query



The above lets the Power Query window opens, now from Home Tab --> Advanced Editor --> And paste the following M-Code by removing whatever you see, and press Done


let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(Source, "Name", "Name - Copy"),
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Duplicated Column", {{"Name", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, " "), type text}}),
    #"Extracted Text After Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter", {{"Name - Copy", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, " ", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd}), type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Extracted Text After Delimiter", List.Distinct(#"Extracted Text After Delimiter"[#"Name - Copy"]), "Name - Copy", "Rate")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"



Lastly, to import it back to Excel --> Click on Close & Load or Close & Load To --> The first one which clicked shall create a New Sheet with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.



For Microsoft-365 you may try-
=LET(
vc,TEXTBEFORE(A2:A7," "),
vr,--TEXTAFTER(A2:A7," ",-1),
a,UNIQUE(vc),
b,TOROW(UNIQUE(vr)),
VSTACK(HSTACK("Name",b),
HSTACK(a,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(a),COLUMNS(b),LAMBDA(rw,col,SUM((B2:B7)*(vc=INDEX(a,rw))*(vr=INDEX(b,1,col))))))))


